# Bluetooth not detecting anything in Ubuntu 16.04 in HP laptop

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, hp

Since I have updated to Ubuntu 16.04 many things have been going wrong. When I turn Bluetooth on and make it visible it doesn't detect any devices, neither does any other device detect my laptop.

I ran the following command in the terminal:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
```

and got:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:2231]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:0050 Validity Sensors, Inc. Swipe Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b001 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:036e Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 25a7:0701  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Can somebody please help me? I tried many things, but couldn't make it work.

Thanks

Comment: This is a known bug. I do not have a solution for 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

> This post was originally written in Polish.  Below is the Google Translated text, translated to English from Polish.

Wrong. Unfortunately, the version of Ubuntu 16.04 is a lot of mistakes I currently also working on ubuntu 16 .Dzisiaj want to download music from your computer to your phone via bluetooth and after switching did not detect anything . when I went to turn on the menu and once again turned on the window it wrote that it is not turned on even though it turned into this option turned off the computer a few times before but it worked for a short time .

The solution is so !

The device connect to your computer and then it will detect it . Or view on your phone settings, bluetooth what is the ip of your bluetooth and type in the window in ubuntu . That should do it ! if there is , unfortunately, you have to upload files such as : sd card . I would recommend for the future.

Comment: Google Translate is not working in Poland? You could translate the answer yourself, right?

Comment: Yes, I did translate. Thank you for the work-around. But in my case, I want to connect my bluetooth headphone to my laptop. That works with my windows laptop, but unfortunately I am not being able to do that in my ubuntu machine :(